# Data is missing from API call to Unsplashed using Swift

Tags: swift, api

Problem:
I was following a tutorial and I cannot seem to get the data loaded when I get a API call from Unsplashed. I registered for an account and used my personal key.

I created my loadData function that should load the data from the API call:

```
func loadData() {
        let key = "my key"
        let url = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?count=30&client_id=\(key)"
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, error) in
                         guard let data = data else {
            print("URLSession dataTask error", error ?? "nil")
            return
        }
            print(data)
            do{
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Photo].self,from: data)
                print(json)
                for photo in json {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.photoArray.append(photo)
                    }
                }
            }catch{
                print("In error")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

I present my data in the content view as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var randomImages = UnsplashData()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I print the data before I use the JSON decoder and there seems to be data there, but when I go to get the JSON it states this error:

```
The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.
```

So is it the way I am using the API key? Or something else?

The photo structure is as follows:

```
struct Photo: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id: String
    var alt_description: String
    var urls: [String: String]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you turn the `data` into a string and _look_ at it and _see_ what's wrong with it?

Comment: Don't share your key :/

Comment: The API call is returning data just fine, maybe its with the `Photo` structure

Comment: How would I turn it into a string? It say invalid conversion

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes its in the photo structure, they might have changed some things since the tutorial, when I just have ID, the JSON that is printed shows the pictures :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the data that you're receiving, it's how you're decoding it that seems to be an issue.

For example, this simple playground example works just fine...

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

struct Sources: Decodable {
    let raw: String
    let full: String
    let regular: String
    let small: String
    let thumbnail: String
}

struct Photo: Decodable {
    let urls: [Sources]
}

let key = "don't post this, that's a bad idea"
let url = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?count=30&client_id=\(key)"

let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, error) in
    guard let data = data else {
        print("URLSession dataTask error", error ?? "nil")
        return
    }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
    do{
        let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Photo].self,from: data)
        print(json)
    }catch{
        print("In error")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}.resume()
```

If you change `print(error.localizedDescription)` to `print(error)` you'll generally get a more accurate description of the error